# Android leaderboard & Achievements deprecate

Tags: android, google-play-services, deprecated, leaderboard, achievements

After updating play-services-games to 11.8.0, Leaderboard and Achievements became deprecate.

Comment: Added Load Achievments

Answer (score 4):

Since I did not find much info about it (and sadly no Stackoverflow topic).
This is how I updated my code to be complaint with the new Android documentation.

**Current high score for player:**

before 11.8.0:

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(getApiClient(), leaderboard, highscoretime[scoreLevel], LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult loadPlayerScoreResult) {
                            if (GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK == loadPlayerScoreResult.getStatus().getStatusCode()) {
                                if (loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore() != null) {
```

After 11.8:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                    .loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(leaderboard, highscoretime[scoreLevel], LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore>>() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onSuccess(AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore> leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData) {
                                                  if (leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData != null) {
                                                      if (leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData.get() != null) {
```

**Displaying Achievements:**

before 11.8.0:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()), RC_REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

after 11.8:

```
Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .getAchievementsIntent()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
                }
            });
```

**Load Achievments**

before 11.8.0

```
private class AchievementClass implements ResultCallback<Achievements.LoadAchievementsResult> {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Achievements.LoadAchievementsResult arg0) {
        try {
            AchievementBuffer aBuffer = arg0.getAchievements();
            Iterator<Achievement> aIterator = aBuffer.iterator();
            while (aIterator.hasNext()) {
                Achievement ach = aIterator.next();
```

after 11.8.0

```
Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
    .load(true).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AnnotatedData<AchievementBuffer>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AnnotatedData<AchievementBuffer> achievementBufferAnnotatedData) {
```

Comment: You should provide clean codes.